# Kendo UI grid- Returning dynamic column definition and data source from the api(web api)

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using a kendo ui grid(using jquery). My requirement is that I have one grid and I need to accommodate dynamic column definitions and data by using model driven approach based on the certain event change in the UI. How can i accommodate custom editors(drop downs, multiselect) in this case. Sample codes below.

```
public class NameModel
{

    [ColumnAttributes(Title = "FirstName", Width = "50px", field = "FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [ColumnAttributes(Title = "LastName", Width = "50px", field = "LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class ColumnAttributes : Attribute
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Width { get; set; }
    public string field { get; set; }
    public string editor { get; set; }
    public bool editable { get; set; }
}

// Main class used to return the grid data and columns based on the type

public class CustomModelWrapper<T>
    {
        public string GridType { get; set; }

        public List<T> GridData { get; set; }

        public List<ColumnAttributes> ColumnHeaders { get; set; }
    }



// Jquery code to bind the 
 $("#grid").removeData('kendoGrid');
        $("#grid").empty();
        var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: data[0].GridData ,
            height: 500,
            columns: data[0].ColumnHeaders,
            editable: true,
        }).data("kendoGrid");
```

Answer (score 0):

This jsbin appears to have the answers for kendo grid. I have a requirement for this also and hope this answer finds you well!

```
     var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      data: gridData,
      schema: {
        model: model,
        parse: parseFunction
      }
    },
    editable: true,
    sortable: true
  });
```

See link - **http://jsbin.com/viqaxoxi/1/edit?html,js,output**